# Upload PDF to product with woocommerce REST API

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api

So i`m trying to upload some products from custom CRM to Woocommerce.

The Wordpress site has Advanced Custom Fields installed and I created an upload field for each product that should contain a PDF with technical specifications.

Can't seem to figure out how to send the PDF from the CRM to Wordpress using it's REST API. Searched the web and didn`t find any info on this.

Here is part of my code:

```
$data = [
   'name' => 'Testing',
   'type' => 'simple',
   'regular_price' => '21.99',
   ....
   'meta_data' => [
   ]
];

$wc_product = $woocommerce->post( 'products', $data);
```

From what I figure there has to be an array inside meta_data but I don't know the fields of the array. Anyone used something like this?

Answer (score 0):

As described in the documentation http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#product-properties, you can use "downloads" key.

```
$data = [
   ...
   'downloads' => [...]
];

$wc_product = $woocommerce->post( 'products', $data);
```

See: http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#product-downloads-properties